# Need script for autocomplete off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to enable the (autocomplete off ) on all of HTML pages i mean need some script to keep it in one place such as script or other way to work for all pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for all pages it's a bit difficult, it depends on the framework you are using to create web pages
You could run a script on page load as follows:

```
$(function(){
    turnOffAutoComplete();
});

function turnOffAutoComplete(){
   $('input[type=text]').attr('autocomplete','off');
}
```

This will turn off autocomplete for all textboxes, but you should add this on every page. Or if you using any development framework you could add it to the "template" page i.e. MasterPage in Web Forms or Layout in MVC. By the way, be aware that if you dynamically add a textbox after the page have loaded you will need to re-call the turnOffAutocomplete function.

Hope it makes sense

Leo

Answer (score 3):

For all HTML page autocomplete off, just include the JS file in all html pages so as per your requirement the code is at one place and can be incorporated in all html files use below code

**a.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
        $( this ).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
    });
});
```

e.g.
**a.html**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src = "a.js"></script>
    </head>
<body></body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('yourInputId').setAttribute( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

or

```
$('yourInput').attr( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

You can see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes with `attr` using jquery;

```
//To remove autocomplete from all input fields
$("input").attr('autocomplete', 'off');

//To add autocomplete to all input fields
$("input").attr('autocomplete', 'on');
```